# How to find a planet with high SOL value?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Polo told me to increase my [SOL](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Sol) value (to reach the next level).

How can I find a planet with high SOL value?
Which properties exactly do I have to looking for?

What exactly do I have to filter or change in the galaxy map to find such a SOL-rich planet?

Comment: Sol appears to be a unit of time (solar days) which makes your question very confusing. The wiki page you linked even says every planet has the same Sol value (though it does say "reference needed" so maybe not true).

Comment: @VanBuzzKill What is the entity to get the needed milestone for polo (if not "SOL")?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the wiki - [Polo](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Specialist_Polo) hands out blueprint rewards as you complete milestones.

One such set of milestone is for [Extreme Survival](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Extreme_Survival) - where you need to spend time on extreme hazard planets (you can spend the time in a cave or building). There appears to be some confusion on the matter, but the milestone seems to be cumulative (the counter only resets on player death, and so you accumulate as you spend time on each hazardous planet you visit).

However, it seems that for the Polo rewards, the effect is not cumulative - so you have to spend over 20 Sols (5 hours) on a single extreme hazard planet before you can unlock all blueprints rewarded for survival.